# discord.py how to add required text/attachment on a slash command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am in the process of updating a discord bot and i want to make it so it has slash commands instead of using the message content route now that discord.py has slash commands, the following is the code i have and this works for making the command and having the user be able to run it but i have had a look at the api reference and cant seem to get it so it has fields for text arguments and making it so it has a required file attachment field.

```
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)


@tree.command(name="test", description = "this is a test command")
async def first_command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"hello {name}", ephemeral=True)
```

I tried using a bunch of different methods of adding an attachment field in the command line but it kept telling me things werent defined and that i had invalid syntax

Comment: "it kept telling me things weren't defined and I had invalid syntax" is not helpful at all to other people here. If you'd actually post the code you tried along with the error we'd be able to tell you what was wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for slash command arguments is the same as regular commands. Just add a parameter to your callback & give it a type annotation.

```py
...
async def first_command(interaction, arg1: str, arg2: discord.Attachment):
    ...
```

For more examples refer to the official app commands examples: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/app_commands/basic.py

Comment: Thank you so much, it was so simple, this is going to help me loads!!